# How can I use external jar files in my Ewon project?

Tags: java, flexy-pool, ewon

I am working with Ewon hardware project which supports javaetk run time environment.

Now some of the functionality like JsonReader, Logger, etc are not available in javaetk. So I download this jar file externally and include it in my project.

Looks fine at Eclipse level! But at run time it shows error on Ewon error blog that class not found! Any suggestions, that how can I use this??

Comment: Have you followed what is mentioned here: https://developer.ewon.biz/content/java-0 ?

Comment: Yes, That's the only thing available for ewon documentation! @AhmedAboumalek

Comment: It looks like etk corresponds to JDK ~1.4 or something like that. So maybe you need to use libs that can work with this version JDK

Answer (score 0):

We could extract external jar files of higher versions of java environment and put it in our project's `bin` folder. So works fine!